# Create video from images, seperate images equally

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to create a video from images, and want to make all the images equal, so for example

```
image-0.png
image-1.png
image-2.png
```

If my audio is 2 minutes I want to show each images equally so: 40 seconds each

my current command:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 1 -i image-%d.png -i audio.wav -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -b:a 192k -vf scale=1280:-2 -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest output.mp4
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the duration of each image to be shown, it will be simple. For your case, it is 40s.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1/40 -i image-%d.png -i audio.wav -vf "fps=fps=5" -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -b:a 192k -vf scale=1280:-2 -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest output.mp4
```

Comment: Add `-r 5` to the output. Some players, like VLC, don't play nice with very low framerate videos.

Comment: If I add `-r 5` to the output, it only shows 40 seconds and 1 image when it should show 80 seconds with 2 images,

Comment: Added -vf "fps=fps=5" in the answer to increase output frame rate as suggested by @Mulvya.